# How to test clean_<fieldname> method?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing

I try to write a test for my clean_ method.

Here is the code for my test

```
def test_clean_restraints(self):
    form = NewTaskForm(dict(restraints="90 20 <>"))
    form.clean_restraints()
```

At this step I receive an error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/django_projects/my_webservice/tasks/tests/test_forms.py", line 12, in test_clean_restraints
    form.clean_restraints()
  File "/home/user/django_projects/my_webservice/tasks/forms.py", line 22, in clean_restraints
    if self.cleaned_data.get('restraints') == '':
AttributeError: 'NewTaskForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

NewTaskForm looks like this:

```
class NewTaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task

    restraints = forms.CharField()
    region = forms.CharField()
    interactions = forms.CharField()

    def clean_restraints(self):
        if self.cleaned_data.get('restraints') == '':
            return self.cleaned_data.get('restraints')
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('restraints').strip().split('\n')
        regexp = re.compile(r'^(\d+)[\t ]+(\d+)[ \t]+([><]{2})?$')
        cleaned_data = []
        for i, line in enumerate(data):
            match = regexp.match(line)
            if not match:
                raise forms.ValidationError(f"Error in restraints in line {i + 1}")
            else:
                rst_1, rst_2, loop_type = match.groups()
                rst_1 = int(rst_1)
                rst_2 = int(rst_2)
                cleaned_data.append((rst_1, rst_2, loop_type))
        return cleaned_data
```

I'm using Django 2.1, python 3.7.1, PyCharm 2018.3.3 Professional
I tried to run it under debugger in PyCharm  but things goes crazy. I receive different error message. It looks like debugger stopped after full form validation ignoring breakpoints. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Note that when you're debugging form cleaning methods in PyCharm, you have to be careful not to set breakpoints at any place *before* the cleaning method itself is called. That's because the debugger itself wants to introspect your form and will call `form.errors` to do that (which calls `form.is_valid()` which calls `form.full_clean()`...) So breakpoints in `clean` aren't reached anymore because `form._errors` are already populated.

Answer (score 2):

You should test the results of the validation process.

```
form = NewTaskForm(dict(restraints="90 20 <>"))
self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
self.assertEqual(form.errors['restraints'], "Error in restraints in line 1")
```

Comment: Why? What if my validation process is very complex? Can't I split it into smaller tests?

Comment: You are actually testing the validation of a specific field if you test with all other fields valid and just the one field not valid. That's how you should do it. Create your form with one specific known error and test that the error is actually happening. That way you're testing each piece of your full validation process.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what was wrong.

`form.cleaned_data` is created in `full_clean()`. Not in constructor as I thought. It also calls every `clean_fieldname()`. So the ugly workaround is something like this:

```
def test_clean_restraints(self):
    initial_data = dict(restraints="90 20 <>")
    form = NewTaskForm()
    form.cleaned_data = initial_data
    form.clean_restraints()
    (...)
```

Comment: There's a simpler solution: write the effective validation in a protected `_clean_restraints(self, cleaned_data)` method, and call this from the public `clean_restraints(self)` - this way you can test `_clean_restraint()` without the "ugly workaround".